# Excel lookup upwards

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to lookup data that is the first occurrence of an ID looking upwards in excel. I would like to stop looking upwards when the cell value is ID is 0.

I have used the following to find the first occurrence when looking upwards:

In Cell D8:

=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:A8=C8),$B$2:B8)

In Cell D9:

=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:A9=C9),$B$2:B9)

For the case of desired outcome = 13 this works, however when there are consecutive IDs I would like to return the top most non-zero data field. Example desired outcome = 15 with the current formula returns 0.

How can I continue looking upwards until the top most ID = 2 before ID =0?

```
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| ID | Data | Lookup Value | Desired Outcome |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 18   |            1 | No Formula      |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 25   |            2 | No Formula      |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 0  | 0    |            0 | 0               |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 13   |            0 | 0               |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 15   |            0 | 0               |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 0    |            0 | 0               |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 0    |            1 | 13              |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 0    |            2 | 15              |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 0  | 0    |            0 | 0               |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
| 0  | 0    |            0 | 0               |
+----+------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: change `1/($A$2:A8=C8)` to `1/(($A$2:A8=C8)*($B$2:B8<>0))` And wrap in IFERROR: `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(($A$2:A8=C8)*($B$2:B8<>0)),$B$2:B8),0)`

Comment: Thanks Scott - solves a potential issue in C8 - still struggling with C9 returning first value when looking upwards rather than last value

Comment: It works for me, see my answer.

Comment: You are right - Formula mistake on my side - Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in D4 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(($A$2:A4=C4)*($B$2:B4<>0)),$B$2:B4),0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put this in D4 and copy down:

```
=IFNA(LOOKUP(9^9,1/B$2:B4^-1/($A$2:A4=C4)),)
```